# Download Azure Resource Template

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager

How can I download Azure Resource Template using PowerShell commands? I want to edit it and then redeploy it. I have tried it but its not giving me proper values. Its giving me empty object array for virtual applications while I have one virtual application on my azure portal. Below is the command I have used.

```
Get-AzureResource -ResourceGroupName Default-Web-BrazilSouth -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName TestGhaffar/web -OutputObjectFormat New -ApiVersion 2015-08-01
```

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not currently available, although it is [under review](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/281804-azure-resource-manager/suggestions/7163577-ability-to-export-a-resource-group-as-a-template).  Another workaround is to view the current JSON representation of your service using https://resources.azure.com.